# Unable to set cookie in clojure ring

Tags: cookies, clojure, clojure-ring

I'm sending the following response in clojure ring:

```
(res/set-cookie
         (res/redirect (env :some-url))
         "some-id"
         (->
          req
          foo-ns/bar
          :id
          )
         {:max-age (* 30 24 60 60 1000) :path "/"})
```

And on printing this response I get:

```
{:status 302, :headers {"Location" "http://localhost:5000"}, :body "", :cookies {"some-id" {:value "1341313515135490454", :max-age 2592000000, :path "/"}}}
```

But on the client side, the cookie isn't set, which I can see in the console. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're using [`ring.response/set-cookie`](https://github.com/ring-clojure/ring/blob/1.8.0/ring-core/src/ring/util/response.clj#L229-L234) to set the cookie. That will set the cookie attributes under `:cookies` in your response map. Before returning the response to the browser, you need to encode those cookies into a `Set-Cookie` header that the browser can understand. To do this, add the [`ring.middleware.cookies/wrap-cookies`](https://github.com/ring-clojure/ring/blob/1.8.0/ring-core/src/ring/middleware/cookies.clj#L176-L218) middleware to your middleware stack.

You should expect your response to look something like:

```clj
{:status 302
 :body ""
 :headers {"Location" "http://localhost:5000"
           "Set-Cookie" "some-id=1341313515135490454; max-age=2592000000; path=/"}}
```